# AdminLTE Menu with Laravel Docker is not updated

Tags: laravel, docker, adminlte

### Summary

Ive installed AdminLTE V3 using docker + Laravel from [Laravel-AdminLTE](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE). I change some of the sidebar menu column such as URL and text. However, it is not updated.

### What I do

I use docker compose. That is why I do `docker-compose down` & `docker-compose up`.
Also `docker-compose build --no-cache`.

### Code

config/adminlte.php

```
    'menu' => [
        // Navbar items:
        [
            'type'         => 'fullscreen-widget',
            'topnav_right' => true,
        ],

        [
            'text' => 'blog',
            'url'  => 'admin/blog',
            'can'  => 'manage-blog',
        ],
        [
            'text'        => 'pages',
            'url'         => 'admin/pages',
            'icon'        => 'far fa-fw fa-file',
            'label'       => 3,
            'label_color' => 'success',
        ],
        ['header' => 'account_settings'],
        [
            'text' => 'profile',
            'url'  => 'profile',  // Change from default
            'icon' => 'fas fa-fw fa-user',
        ],
~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy a file from `src/vendor/jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte/config/adminlte.php` to `src/config/adminlte.php`.

Also I edit it and work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).